# ServiceStack ORM Lite custom sql LIKE statement wildcard

Tags: ormlite-servicestack

How do we use a LIKE with wildcards in a custom sql with servicestack ORMLite?

Following code does not seem to work:

```
var sql="SELECT TOP 10 Id,Value FROM SomeTable WHERE Value Like '%@term%'"
var results = Db.Select<CustomDTO>(sql, new {term = "stringToSearch"})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the wildcard to the param value, e.g:

```
var sql = "SELECT Id,Value FROM SomeTable WHERE Value Like @term";
var results = db.Select<SomeTable>(sql, new { term = "%foo%" });
```

You can [run this Live Example on Gistlyn to test it](http://gistlyn.com/?gist=3716a91483d032c1951d8c274a36478f&collection=2cc6b5db6afd3ccb0d0149e55fdb3a6a).